# How to use IMPORTXML on Google Spreadsheet to get premarket value for a stock?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the current pre-market price for [this](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/mtsl) stock. This is the formula I'm trying:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/mtsl", "//bg-quote[@session='pre']")
```

I'm not getting the value:

[image: Result]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to read a stock price on [MarketWatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/) in Sheets. Unfortunately you can't use `=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/oln", "/")` because you will get a JavaScript response like this one:

```js
(function(window) {
  try {
    if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined') {
      sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
    }
  } catch (e) {}
})(window);
#d__fFH {
  position: absolute;top: -5000 px;left: -5000 px
}
#d__fF {
  font - family: serif;
  font - size: 200 px;
  visibility: hidden
}
#fwqssyztxufxfzwwduebdqwxedwrzazqaaavux {
  display: none!important
}
```

This behaviour occurs because [`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) is expecting a [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) page in the URL, and since this URL doesn't address a XML-compatible file it will return the page load as best effort. In this case, the server elegantly raises an error because it requires a defined session storage to determine the browser cookie protocol. To prevent this incompatibility, you can use an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) code to fetch the stock price like this one below:

```js
function listingPrice() {
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/mtsl")
    .getContentText().match(/(<meta name="price" content=")(.*)(?=")/)[2];
}
```

In that example I have used [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) to get the page, [`HTTPResponse.getContentText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) to read it's contents and [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to capture the price with a [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). To prevent intraday values you could develop a condition like this example:

```js
function listingPrice() {
  var stock = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/mtsl").getContentText();
  if (stock.match(/(<div class="status">)(.*)(?=<\/div>)/)[2] == "Premarket") {
    return stock.match(/(<meta name="price" content=")(.*)(?=">)/)[2];
  } else {
    return "NASDAQ:MTSL is trading at this time.";
  }
}
```

Then you can save the price on the Sheet with:

```js
function refreshSheet() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue(listingPrice());
}
```

[`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) will open the active sheet to select the A1 range with [`Sheet.getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) and write the price using [`Range.setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue). Please, don't hesitate to ask me further questions.